# As we know we cannot instantiate, but i have gone through a code and found that object is created and how?

Tags: java, spring, loose-coupling

I have this interface

```
public interface GamingConsole {
    void up();
    void down();
    void left();
    void right();
}
```

This is the class where we are instantiating

```
public class GameRunner {
    private GamingConsole game;  // this is interface that we are instantiating 

    public GameRunner(GamingConsole game) {
        this.game = game;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running Game" + game);
        game.up();
        game.down();
        game.left();
        game.right();
    }
}
```

how we are able to run private GamingConsole game; ??

I am calling in this class

```
public class AppGamingBasicJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // var game = new MarioGame();
        // var game = new SuperContraGame();
        var game = new PacManGame();
        var gameRunner = new GameRunner(game);
        gameRunner.run();
    }

}
```

I was learning spring(loose coupling specifically), during this gone through a problem in which we are instantiating interface and theoretically we cannot do that, i wanted to know what actually is happening here, what we are doing here and how my code is working.

I have tried finding solution multiple places but not able to find exact.

Comment: To _instantiate_ is to create a new object. You've done that here: `new PacManGame()`. Note that assuming `PacManGame implements GamingConsole`, then `PacManGame` _is a_ `GamingConsole`, and thus can be assigned according to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (the "L" in SOLID) via `GamingConsole game = new PacManGame();`. So `GameRunner` isn't _instantiating_ a `GamingConsole`, it's simply receiving a reference to an existing one.

Comment: You are not instantiating `GamingConsole`, you are instantiating `PacManGame`, which obviously implements `GamingConsole`, otherwise you would have a compilation error.

Comment: It should be noted you can always implement an anonymous subclass of an interface: `GamingConsole ex = new GamingConsole() { public void up() { ... } ... };`

Comment: Lets say we have `interface Fruit{}` and `class Apple implements Fruit{}`. When we do something like `Fruit fruit = new Apple();` we are NOT instantiating `Fruit` interface, but `Apple` class. What creates instance is `new` operator, so at `new Apple()` instance of Apple is created and reference to that instance is returned. Then we simply store that *reference* in `Fruit fruit` *variable*.